# using ajax or not when displaying new records in asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner in MVC. In my application, I list categories (as a button) on the left hand-side (inside a div). Just right to this div, there is another div which displays the items associated with the clicked category.

When a category button is clicked, I am planning to call the action of the controller that will retrieve the Items from the database and add these Items to the ViewModel (e.g., `model.Items = db.Items...`), and then call the View with the updated Model and display the Items.

However, I am curios if it is better to make an Ajax call here and use a partial view for displaying the Items of the clicked category.

If feel like between these two approaches in my scenario only difference will be the page-refresh, they should work the same in terms of speed since both of them require the same database call.

Can anyone share good practices in MVC for such scenarios?

Comment: Using ajax will be (marginally) faster because it does not require a page refresh - you just update the existing DOM

Comment: @StephenMuecke which approach is commonly adopted in MVC applications?

Comment: That really depends on too numerous factors. You really need to make that decision yourself (and its not really clear why you would have `@Html.BeginForm()` - why would you need to submit a form when all you seem to want is to get data?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that was my bad (I am still a beginner), I fixed it. Thanks! Can you please give 1 or 2 examples of these factors?

Comment: You question is far too broad, but in your case, using ajax would seem to be the best approach - you just pass the ID of the category to a controller method that filters the data based on the ID and returns a partial view, which you then append to the DOM because it means you do not have to regenerate all the other elements in the page (e.g. the list of categories)

Comment: Using jquery would be the best approach for this scenario. As you don't have to load the layout page which will have  to render the scripts and stuff all over again. Stick on to Ajax calls in MVC as much as possible, The technologies are being improved and lot of single page applications are out there, And if we still use a page load for every new request then there is no point.

Comment: @Reddy I wish I could mark this as correct answer! I wonder also if it is good practice to use Partial Views with Ajax instead of dealing with Json data?

Comment: This is a good point, Both partial Views and Json hold the same weight depending on the scenario. Lets say you have a partial view with lot of if checks and loops and build the HTML according to if etc etc, in such scenario using Partial view is actually better, Because if we try to build the same thing in Jquery using json its possible but wont be that easy and we might make errors during development. But if the requirement is like updating a grid, dynamic drop down, or dealing with some Jquery plugins in the page I think Json data would be better, as many plugins play with json data itself.

Comment: @Reddy thanks! I wish you could compile your comments as an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will add it as an answer, give me few minutes

Comment: @Reddy thanks! I heard using AngularJS in MVC is also strongly encouraged, is that right?

Comment: oh yes, I hate myself for not getting a chance to put my hands on Angular But definitely yes these two combination is a Bomb!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> using ajax or not when displaying new records in asp.net mvc

Using jquery would be the best approach for this scenario. As you don't have to load the layout page which will have to render the scripts and stuff all over again. `Stick on to Ajax calls in MVC as much as possible`, The technologies are being improved and a lot of single page applications are out there, And if we still use a page load for every new request then there is no point.

> *Coming to comparison between passing back Partial View And Json Data*.  *Which is better to use in the application design*?

Both partial Views and Json data hold the same weight depending on the scenario.

- `When to use partial view`: Lets say you have a Model and you have to build the view HTML by lot of if checks and loops and possibly some c# code ( in rare scenarios), etc, in such scenario using Partial view would be the better choice, Because if we try to build the same thing in Jquery using json data the complexity of the code required would be high compared to what can be done in Partial views, But still achieving it is possible but wont be that easy and we might make errors during development.
- `When to use Json Data`: If the requirement is like updating a grid, generating dynamic drop down or dealing with some Jquery plugins in the page I think Json data would be better, as many plugins play with json data as the core requirement.

---

**A Small Example Of Deciding Between Partial View And Json Data** - *interested folks and read through*

Lets take a scenario where we have to display a grid of data. This is our initial requirement. So we can happily build our viewModel with data and pass it to our partial view and render the table using for loops. All set, Now the requirement changes and we are asked to build sorting, filtering and paging stuff in our table. So at present we look for a plugin that can be easily integrated with current code and yes the easy one to use at this scenario is [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/). Ok, we wrote a small Jquery to apply the plugin to the table and all set we have the fancy stuff ready.

Now here is the tricky part, we are asked to add functionalities like add, edit, delete record from the table. Yes its possible but is little tricky to get it done in the best possible way with the current code which we have. What we tend to do is, when ever there is a change in the table we plan to recall the partial view. Which works fine but still asking to ourselves just to delete one record from the table is it good to reload the partial view again?? Definitely NOT,

What can we do? When ever there is any add, edit, delete operation we hit the controller to update the database and we can `make the controller return a JSON data` and just pass this Json data to the plugin API and refresh the table, This will be more neat and faster. So here you see JSON data would be the better choice. Also some might even want to make it more cleaner by just playing with that one record of data and writing up some jquery code to manipulate the table, which is absolutely fine, But it requires us to pass the Json data itself back from controller.

So having this done, we can go back and refactor our code to make partial view to use json data for the grid initially too or leave it as it is saying the initial load will be a partial view, but following operations would be a json result, which is fine but I feel let all the data related stuff come from one point.

So that explains how a simple module can change from being a partial view to then use Json data. There are scenarios where the story is the other way around, You have to pick the right one for the right work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes AJAX is faster and good way to update detail in same page without refresh.
For that you have to create `JsonResult` method in controller. It will give you result in Json.
Try JQuery Template plugin for repeated code.

```
<script id="trTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
            <tr>
                {{each $data}}
                    <td>${Col}</td>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>
</script>    
<table id="containerTable">
</table>
```

AJAX Call

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'Your JsonResult Method URL',
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (data) {
                // It will pass data to template and template will bind parsing json
              $('#trTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#containerTable');
            //Business logic
        },
        complete: function () {
             // Your Code
        }
    });
```

Your JsonResult Method

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetData(ViewModel model)
    {
    // Your Code here       
    }
```

Comment: I can use also partial view instead of jquery template, right?

Comment: yes but you can not use condition and other functionality. Please refer support document it will help you other way.